# How to change the value of a field in one table based on input from another table in MS Access 2013 web app

Tags: ms-access

I am trying out Access web apps and am quite new to Access in general. I am currently working on an app that records how many volunteer days someone has given towards our projects, and assigns points. They can redeem points for rewards. I have two tables, "Records", and "Administration". "Records" stores both the number of points the person has redeemed, points earned, and their total points remaining. In "Administration", I want to be able to create a record each time the person redeems points (ex. +1), and each time they have earned points (ex. +2). Once the record is saved, I want to be able to press a button in "Administration" that automatically searches for the person's record in "Records" based on the name on the selected record, and then changes the values based on that record (ex. +1 to redeemed points and +2 to earned points, and then totaling the remaining points to +1). I have everything finished up to the button.

Thank you very much for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, should not change value. Aggregate data should be calculated when needed from the raw data records. Trying to store an aggregate value has risk of that value getting 'out of sync' from the raw data and creates a data validation nightmare.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Why if I use a checkbox for each record in "Administration" which gets disabled after update (when it's checked) and changes the value?

Comment: Again, saving aggregate data is bad practice. It kills data integrity and accountability. There is no easy way to substantiate the value as it is 'disconnected' from the raw data. You would have do a calc on raw data anyway to support the saved value if it was ever questioned. But if there is no raw data then there is no way to substantiate the validity of the value modified and saved by a checkbox or other control click. Do whatever satisfies your needs and deal with the consequences.